# How to check a value in an integer range in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

For example, the integer range is separated by comma, such as "4450-4499, 4700-4805, 9920-9959". How to check if an integer is in this range?

Answer (score 1):

Paste values:

- Cell `A1` = `4450-4499, 4700-4805, 9920-9959`
- Cell `B1` = `4450` or any number

And use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(JOIN("",QUERY(
{ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,", ")),"(\d+)")*1),
ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,", ")),"-(\d+)")*1)},
"where Col1 <= "&B1&" and Col2 >= "&B1&"",0))*1,0)>0
```

Will return true bacause `4450` is in range `4450-4499`.

Answer (score 0):

This function takes a number and the range and performs the check, but beware that it has no precautions, so the data provided must fit the format you gave:

```
function inRange(number, range) {
  range = range.split(", ");
  range = range.map(function(x) {return x.split("-")});

  for (var i in range) {
    if (number >= range[i][0] && number <= range[i][1]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```